# EF Core Remove PK

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm looking to remove the primary key of a table I created with a many to many relationship

tldr of table:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_stack 
(
    ParentId int,
    ChildId int,
    Primary Key (ParentId, ChildId)
);
```

The class for the db entity:

```
public class TmpExample 
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

In the context we create the db entity and set up the model...

```
public virtual DbSet<TmpExample> StackQuestion { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TmpExample>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("tmp_stack");
        entity.HasKey(x => new { x.ParentId, x.ChildSettingId })
              .HasName("PRIMARY");
    });
}
```

My question is once we get to the `Remove` from EF Core, we usually remove based on the PK

How do I do that in EF Core?

I have tried the below delete

```
public async Task DeleteAsync(int parentId, int childId, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    object key = new {parentId, childId};
    _context.Remove(key);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(ct);
}
```

which results in the following error:

> The entity type '<>f__AnonymousType1<int, int>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.

Comment: `var key = new TmpExample { ParentId  = parentId, ChildId = childId };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the actual object, not an anoymous type, otherwise EF doesn't know what it is.

```cs
var key = new TmpExample { ParentId  = parentId, ChildId = childId }; 
_context.Remove(key);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(ct);
```

Note that only the primary key needs to be set if you are removing.